# Ansible reboot without Shutdown Event Tracker windows

Tags: windows, ansible, reboot

OS: Win2016 Server

Ansible: 2.9

Hi all!

I use in ansible the "win_reboot" module to reboot a win hosts, but many times some hosts when restart show a "Shutdown Event Tracker" windows.

How do fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

I disable this with win_regedit module.

```
win_regedit:
  path: "HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\Reliability"
  name: "ShutdownReasonOn"
  data: "8"
  type: "dword"
```

Cordially!